# jQuery hover event (as well as append and detach) to fire on dynamically loaded content

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, hover

Morning.

I am trying to add a hover event to images which are loaded dynamically, in addition I also have to append the element I am hovering and then detach it from within the hover function.

The event will work the first time on the initially loaded content, but won't fire after this.

Here is myjQuery:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    $('#rightImageContent img').mouseover(function() {
        $('a.spy_glass').show().appendTo('#rightImageContent');
    });
    $('#rightImageContent img').mouseout(function() {
        $('a.spy_glass').hide().detach();
    });
});
```

All the code is available [here](http://dev.slackwise.org.uk/photography/) but if you do want more html or jquery please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Try to the `mouseover` and `mouseout` out of the `ajaxComplete`.

The right images will be a `$('#rightImageContent img')` always if they are loaded by ajax or not

```
  $('#rightImageContent img').mouseover(function() {
        $('a.spy_glass').show().appendTo('#rightImageContent');
    });
    $('#rightImageContent img').mouseout(function() {
        $('a.spy_glass').hide().detach();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `"#rightImageContent` always exists:

```
$(function() {
    $('a.spy_glass').appendTo('#rightImageContent').hide();
    $("#rightImageContent").on({
        mouseenter: function() {
            $('a.spy_glass').show();
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            $('a.spy_glass').hide();
        }
    }, "img");
});
```

I also changed the events because "hover" is not `mouseover mouseout`, but `mouseenter mouseleave`

You are also removing it from the dom, so the selector cannot find it once it's removed. You could just toggle the display like I do though.

Comment: OK that is appending and detaching, but only firing once. Re-entering the mouseevent does nothing, as if detach has removed the element completely. Or the function cannot fire again.

Comment: @lharby heh I just noticed you are removing it from the dom, so it cannot be found with `a.spy_glass`. Let me know if the solution of just hiding or showing is not good enough, I can then edit the code back to what you have but use references instead of selector, because selectors only work on something that is attached on the page.

Comment: Yes, maybe I should explain #rightImageContent always exists but #rightImageContent img is created dynamically.

Comment: @lharby yes that is my assumption, it's your `.detach` that cannot work with a selector after

Comment: @lharby I don't understand. what id? `.detach` removes the element from the DOM - It cannot be found with any selector after that. You can see the event is firing all the time by simply adding `console.log` in the functions. It's your detach that is the problem.

Comment: As I understand it empty() and remove() both remove the element from the DOM, detach only removes it temporarily so that the item can be appended or reattached later. It still exists in the DOM.

Comment: Yes your code should work and makes sense, only I think there is a problem with the dynamically loaded content.

Comment: @lharby no it doesn't exist in the dom (It is detached, disconnected from it). `.detach()` just doesn't remove events or data from the element. Other than that, it's the same as `.remove()`. `.empty()` is completely different animal. From http://api.jquery.com/detach/ : *Description: Remove the set of matched elements from the DOM.*

Answer (score 0):

Use .on()

```
  $(document).on({mouseenter:function(){
                                        $('a.spy_glass').show().appendTo('#rightImageContent');
                                        },
                  mouseleave:function() {
                                        $('a.spy_glass').hide().detach();
                                        }},'#rightImageContent img');
```

Answer (score 0):

OK got this to work it, does the job:

```
$(function() {
        $("#rightImageContent").on({
            mouseenter: function() {
                $('a#spyGlass').show().appendTo('#rightImageContent');
            },
            mouseleave: function() {
                $('a#spyGlass').hide().appendTo('body');
            }
        });
    });
```